# Contar registros distintos com condição de filtragem em outro campo

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Pessoal preciso realizar uma contagem de quantos registros distintos existem em um campo, porem minha condição de filtragem é feita com base em outro campo.

Exemplo de como estão organizados os dados:

```
PDV |   DESC
----------------
410 | "Automa"
410 | "Automa"
410 | "Automa"
150 | "Automa"
150 | "Automa"
150 | "Automa"
831 | "Automa"
831 | "Automa"
```

Query que eu fiz:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(PDV) FROM Table WHERE DESC ='Automa'
```

O que eu preciso é contar quantos PDVs diferentes existem com a mesma descrição.

O resultado que eu obtive foi `8` o que eu espero receber é `3` ja que eu tenho 3 PDVs distintos

Comment: Qual o seu SGBD?

Comment: MSSQL. Funcionou! muito obrigado!

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha lhe atendido não esqueça de aceitá-la como correta para que auxilie pessoas com dúvidas similares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize um [`DISTINCT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187831(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) aliado ao [`COUNT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PDV)
  FROM table
 WHERE desc = 'Automa'
```

---

> [`COUNT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Essa função retorna o número de itens encontrados em um grupo.

---

> [`DISTINCT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187831(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
>
> A palavra-chave DISTINCT elimina linhas duplicadas dos resultados de uma instrução SELECT.